# Como armazenar e exibir apenas o horário? C# MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime

Preciso pegar um horário de entrada e um de saída de dois textboxs, armazenar no banco e posteriormente exibir, meu código está assim:

```
//Cadastro
//No evento do botão cadastrar
entradaSaida.HrEntrada = Convert.ToDateTime(txtHrEntrada.Text);
entradaSaida.HrSaida = Convert.ToDateTime(txtHrSaida.Text);

//No método insert do banco
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hrentrada", entradaSaida.HrEntrada);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hrsaida", entradaSaida.HrSaida);

//Pegando do banco
entradaSaida.HrEntrada = (DateTime)dr["hrentrada"];
entradaSaida.HrSaida = (DateTime)dr["hrsaida"];

//Exibindo no ListView
materialListView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] {item.HrEntrada.ToShortTimeString(), item.HrSaida.ToShortTimeString()}));
```

Quando eu armazeno, o que vem do textBox é algo como "13:00", mas na hora de exibir no ListView todos os horários ficam zerados "00:00". Se alguém puder me ajudar agradeço

Comment: Apenas 13:00 está armazenado em txtHrEntrada.Text? ou uma data completa com horário?

Comment: Outra coisa, de onde saiu o "item" da sua ListView? Está faltando algum trecho do seu código eu acho. Poste o trecho completo para conseguirmos te ajudar.

Comment: no txtBox está armazenado apenas "13:00" mesmo. Sobre o Item, esse código é de um foreach na lista, dai peguei só a parte que adiciona o item mesmo

Comment: Caro Rafael você está gravando como, você faz como as operações de CRUD?

Answer (score 1):

> Como armazenar e exibir apenas o horário?

Para armazenar apenas horário no MySQL você pode usar o tipo [TIME](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time.html) específico para isso, conforme informado no comentário.

---

Não há erro nenhum na parte em que converte a data para apenas horário. Está vindo **00:00** por que é o que está armazenado no valor que você recuperou no `foreach` que omitiu da pergunta.

Não tem como fazer uma análise mais completa que isso.

```
var horario1 = Convert.ToDateTime("13:00");
var horario2 = Convert.ToDateTime("15:19");

//Quando você converte uma string apenas com a hora o resultado é a data de hoje e o horário da string:
Console.WriteLine(horario1); //resultado 4/24/2019 1:00:00 PM
Console.WriteLine(horario2); //resultado 4/24/2019 3:19:00 PM

//Se seu código está correto, quando for imprimir a hora dos items que armazenou acima com ToShortTimeString o resultado vai ser oque você espera mesmo:
Console.WriteLine(horario1.ToShortTimeString());
Console.WriteLine(horario2.ToShortTimeString());
```

[Veja aqui o código acima rodando e imprimindo os horários normalmente.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4uEqfa)

Avaliando tudo isso, seu erro está provavelmente na forma que está armazenando e/ou recuperando as informações do banco de dados.

Consulte a [documentação da microsoft sobre o ToShortTimeString](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.datetime.toshorttimestring?view=netframework-4.8) e debug seu código depois que entender tudo que está utilizando pra achar seu problema.

Comment: Aonde você viu que não tem o tipo para gravar horas no MySQL, porque existe sim!

Comment: Existe tipo específico para horário sim: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time.html

Comment: Obrigado @VirgilioNovic vou corrigir essa informação.

Comment: @hkotsubo erro meu, não uso MySQL no dia dia e minha consulta rápida a documentação foi bem falha, li apenas esse trecho (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html), o TIME seria o próximo tipo abordado. Valeu!